# How do I return values after running a function from binding a key?

Tags: python, tkinter, file-structure

I have a function that is run when a key is pressed, this is done using the following:

```
root.bind("<Key>", lambda event:KeyPressed(event, string_x, ...)
```

This function appends the letter associated with the key that was pressed to `string_x`. Once it's done this, I need it to return the new value of `string_x` so that it can be used in `main.py`. My file structure is as follows:

```
-> main.py
-> keypressed.py
```

I have tried parsing the function bound to the event another "callback" function, that should run a function in `main.py`, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you show what exactly it was that you attempted? Because there's no way to get the return value of the callback function.

Comment: You can't "return a value" from this function. You can instead update a class or global variable, post a message to a queue, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return values after running a function from binding a key?

You can't. When a bound function is called, it's not called by your code. It's called from the internals of `mainloop`. Anything returned by a bound function -- except for the special string "break" -- is ignored. Returning the string "break" will cause any further processing of that event to stop.

You will need to set a global variable if not using classes, or set an instance variable if using classes.